# accidentally overwrote hard drive with another app how do I retrieve my 3 years back of my life

Tags: hard-drive

I was trying to make a hard drive a second hard drive into a clone drive and I accidentally installed the clone drive over my main hard drive and now I lost 3 years of my life I'm trying to get back is there any help to retrieve the data

Comment: restore from backup... otherwise, immediately stop using the drive by disconnecting it ... then update your post with a clear description of what you have done ... in the end  a professional data recovery lab may be your best course of action

Comment: Did you overwrite the entire drive or did you realise your mistake immediately and cancel the copy? What software did you use? What settings?

Comment: [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) can be used to recover at least some of the data if a backup doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

If you cloned the drive on the block level, ie. overwriting the destination, there's no recovery other than from backup.